# Get Slim with PHP-DI (autowiring) working

Tags: php, slim, autowired, php-di

I tried to get slim with [PHP-DI](http://php-di.org/) and [Autowiring](http://php-di.org/#autowiring) working, without success. Maybe I have a wrong understanding of autowiring.

I setup a new project and created the following `Index.php`:

```php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use userservice\core\services\UserServiceInterface;
use userservice\infrastructure\services\UserService;
use userservice\webservice\controller\UsersController;
use DI\Container;

$app = \DI\Bridge\Slim\Bridge::create();
$container = $app->getContainer();
$container->set(UserServiceInterface::class, UserService::class);
$container->set(UsersController::class, UsersController::class);


$app->get('/user', [UsersController::class, 'get']);

$app->run();
```

The `UsersController`

```
namespace userservice\webservice\controller;

use userservice\core\services\UserServiceInterface;

class UsersController{

    /**
     *
     * @var UserServiceInterface
     */
    private $userService;

    public function __construct(UserServiceInterface $userService) {
        $this->userService = $userService;
    }

    public function get(\Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $response, \Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface $request){
        //$user = $this->userService->get();
        $response->getBody()->write("Test");
        return $response;
    }
}
```

In the example above I get the following error-message:

```
Non-static method userservice\webservice\controller\UsersController::get() should not be called statically in
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution how I can use PHP-DI autowiring with mapping to interfaces:

```php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use userservice\core\services\UserServiceInterface;
use userservice\infrastructure\services\UserService;
use userservice\webservice\controller\UsersController;
use userservice\core\repositories\UserRepositoryInterface;
use userservice\infrastructure\repositories\UserRepository;

/**
 * Mapping of classes to interfaces
 */
$definitions = [
    //REPOSITORIES
    UserRepositoryInterface::class => DI\get(UserRepository::class),

    //SERVICES
    UserServiceInterface::class => DI\get(UserService::class),
];

$builder = new DI\ContainerBuilder();
$builder->addDefinitions($definitions);
$container = $builder->build();
$app = \DI\Bridge\Slim\Bridge::create($container);
$app->get('/user', [UsersController::class, 'get']);

$app->run();
```